# How to make Flutter sign up with more fields?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

My sign up page has the following fields Names, password, confirm password and email but it seems flutter firebase only works for email and password.
How do I make more fields work in the below code:

```
createUser()async{
    if (checkFields()){
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: _email, password: _password)
          .then((user){
        print('signed in as ${user.uid}');

        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> (Usertype())));

      }).catchError((e){
        print(e);
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hello, did my answer solved your problem?

Comment: Once I have uid, is it advisable to create a new users collection with lot of fields per user ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot make Firebase accept `Names` on sign up event.
But you can update user information after sign up.

Use `updateProfile` method after authentication is successfully complete.
You can check [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users) as Android example, and [here](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/4d702ad711f014760434122ce2bd06d2f41b5c6c/packages/firebase_auth/lib/src/firebase_user.dart#L132) as the method from the Flutter package.

In your case,

```
createUser()async{
    if (checkFields()){
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: _email, password: _password)
          .then((user){
        print('signed in as ${user.uid}');
        var userUpdateInfo = new UserUpdateInfo(); //create user update object
        userUpdateInfo.displayName = name; //set user display name to your variable.
        await firebaseAuth.updateProfile(userUpdateInfo); //update the info
        await user.reload(); //reload the user data

        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> (Usertype())));

      }).catchError((e){
        print(e);
      });
    }
  }
```